# How does initcheck affect execution of CUDA program?

Tags: cuda

I am working on a program that uses multiple device contexts, each being processed in separate stream (often synchronized).  The problem is, it produces correct results only when run under `cuda-memcheck --tool initcheck`. My question is:

How does running program under `initcheck` modify it's execution ?

Due to level of complication i'm not able to share any code or produce MCVE, so please treat this question rather generally. The program have been checked with all the debugging tools provided by nvidia and produced no errors.

Comment: I would guess serialisation.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/#what-is-initcheck:

> The initcheck tool is a run time uninitialized device global memory
>   access detector. This tool can identify when device global memory is
>   accessed without it being initialized via device side writes, or via
>   cudaMemcpy/cudaMemset.
>
> Currently, this tool only supports detecting accesses to device global
>   memory.
>   [...]
>   Note: The initcheck tool does not perform any memory access error checking.

If you do not actually detect any errors, but obtain different results when the tools are off, my first suspect would be some concurrency error (read-after-write, etc...). Tools like the one above usually slows some parts of the program, which may affect that kind of problems.

This is just a guess however...

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Docs was my first choice, but lack of information forced me to ask the question here. I also bet on some concurrency issues, but have no clue how to identify their origins. I was hoping that `initcheck` does something more than just adding overhead -  investigating what happens around it would be good place to start.

Comment: It does something more: it checks if you only use initialized memory - but if you get no errors, then that is not an issue.

Comment: The issue turned out to be different. It looks like device pointer arithmetic on host side did not work correctly while passing to kernel. Anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: Interesting. Pointer arithmetic should behave the same way on either side. I would like to see the issue you found!